# Anti-symmetric operators for the Dirac or Majorana spinors

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-topology, quantum-field-theory, string-theory

In a Zoom lecture given by a mathematical physics professor, if I recalled correctly, he explained that the in 1+1 dimensional spacetime (or 2 dimensions in short), the "action" of fermions (spinors) has an anti-symmetric Dirac operator.

1. Say, if the $\psi$ is a Dirac spinor, he wrote down an action
   $$
   \int d^2x \sqrt{g} \bar{\psi} (i \gamma^\mu D_\mu) \psi
   $$
   and (I think) he claims that the operator $(i \gamma^\mu D_\mu)$ is an anti-symmetric matrix.
2. Say, if the $\chi$ is a Majorana spinor, he wrote down an action
   $$
   \int d^2x \sqrt{g}  {\chi} (i \gamma^\mu D_\mu) \chi
   $$
   and (I think) he claims that the operator $(i \gamma^\mu D_\mu)$ is also an anti-symmetric matrix.

> Is this true that the anti-symmetric matrix has something to do with these fermions (spinors)? or fermion statistics? Why?

p.s. Maybe the first case the $D$ operator is complex, and the second case that the $D$ operator is real (?).

Comment: This seems difficult to parse. Anti-symmetric in what indices? The usual requirement is that $\gamma^{0} $ be Hermitean and the $\gamma^{i} $ anti-Hermitean. One can find Hermitean matrices that are symmetric, and ones that are antisymmetric ... perhaps a definite representation of the Dirac matrices is intended? Certainly, $iD_{\mu } $ is Hermitean. And all this shouldn't depend crucially on this being in 1+1 dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of the Hamiltonian $H$ the antisymmetry follows simply: Majorana fields $\Psi(x,t)$ are real, and they satisfy a real wave equation
$$\partial\Psi/\partial t =-iH\Psi,$$
where $iH$ is real, hence $H$ is imaginary. Since $H$ must also be Hermitian, it means that $H^T=-H$ (antisymmetric).

<sub>More explicitly, $H=\gamma_{\rm M}^\mu \partial_\mu$, with $\gamma_{\rm M}^\mu$ the Dirac matrices in the Majorana representation, for which $\gamma_{\rm M}$ is a purely imaginary $4\times 4$ matrix. The antisymmetry of $H$ becomes manifest if we discretize the derivative operator so that $H$ becomes a matrix and $H_{nm}=-H_{mn}$.</sub>

Comment: The plot thickens ... now, $H$ is constructed from the spatial components only - furthermore, since $H$ is related to $i\gamma_{M}^{i} D_i $ through a factor $\gamma_{M}^{0} $, which is antisymmetric, this would actually imply that $i\gamma_{M}^{i} D_i $ is symmetric, not antisymmetric. Could it be that the spoken word in a Zoom lecture, remembered from memory, is not quite as reliable as the written word?

Comment: I think the answer is very nice and seems perfectly fine -- I will accept it in a week if no other better answers. (Voted up)

Comment: thank you again - accepted

Comment: Sorry, may I confirm: What do we mean by the matrix is real or imaginary?

Comment: (1) when we say matrix $P$ is Hermitian, it mens $P^\dagger =P$,.  when we say matrix $P$ is anti Hermitian, it mens $P^\dagger = -P$,.

Comment: (2) when we say matrix $P$ is symmetric, it mens $P^T =P$,.  when we say matrix $P$ is anti symmetric, it mens $P^T =-P$.

Comment: (3)  What do we mean by the matrix $P$ is real or imaginary? to be mathematical precise?

Comment: (PS. Hermitian matrix has real eigenvalues.)

Comment: a matrix is real if the matrix elements are $\in\mathbb{R}$; a Hermitian matrix $P$ is real if $P=P^T$.

Comment: The answer seems to be in general and independent of space time dimensions, yes or no? thanks!

Comment: yes it is as you say.